# Number of integer solutions to a system of Diophantine inequalities

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and  $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $a+b\in(N/2,2N)$ (then of course $\max\{a,b\}\simeq N$). I'm interested in getting an upper bound (in terms of $N$) for the number of positive integer solutions $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ to the system of inequalities:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
|m^2+n^2-a^2-b^2|<N^\alpha,\\
|m^3+n^3-a^3-b^3|<N^\alpha,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $\alpha\in(1,2)$ is a fixed constant.

The best I can do is to observe that this system has at most as many solutions as the single inequality
\begin{align*}
|m^3+n^3-a^3-b^3|<N^\alpha
\end{align*}
and then use a fact that for a fixed $k\in (-N^\alpha, N^\alpha)\cap\mathbb{Z}$ the equation
\begin{align*}
m^3+n^3=a^3+b^3+k
\end{align*}
has at most $(a^3+b^3+k)^\epsilon\simeq N^{3\epsilon}$ solutions, where $\epsilon>0$ is an arbitrary small constant. Since there are $N^\alpha$ choices of $k$ it gives the upper bound $N^{\alpha+\epsilon}$, for arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$.
Can one do better?

Comment: The best approach might be to consider the real solution set, which I think is always the union of two regions, and use standard results to count lattice points in regions. In the limit as $a,b \to \infty$, unless $a,b$ are very close together, the functions $m^2+n^2$ and $m^3+n^3$ will behave approximately linearly near $a,b$ and these shapes will regions will converge to long, thin rectangles. A bound will then be the area of the rectangle or its diameter, whichever is larger. But getting explicit estimates might prove tricky...

Comment: I see, I'll try this approach. Thanks a lot, Will!